# Rationalize this

Tags: radicals, rationalising-denominator

I'm having trouble rationalizing the denominator of this fraction. Would you kindly explain this to a fellow self-learning math student?
$$\frac{10}{\sqrt[4]{3}-1}$$  knowing that $a^n-b^n=\left(a-b\right)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}\cdot b+a^{n-3}\cdot b^2+...+a\cdot b^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\right)$

$a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Let $a=\sqrt[4]{3}$ and $b=1$. The idea is to get an expression with no radicals in the denominators.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't see how the tip helps.

$$
\frac{10}{\sqrt[4]{3}-1} = \frac{10}{\sqrt[4]{3}-1}\frac{\sqrt[4]{3}+1}{\sqrt[4]{3}+1} = \frac{10(\sqrt[4]{3}+1)}{\sqrt{3}-1}=\frac{10(\sqrt[4]{3}+1)}{\sqrt{3}-1}\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}+1} = \frac{10(\sqrt[4]{3}+1)(\sqrt{3}+1)}{2}
$$

Comment: Well, of course $\frac{a^n-b^n}{\text{stuff}}=a-b$ and then $\text{stuff}$ goes up when you substitute.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{10}{\sqrt[4]{3}-1} = \dfrac{5\cdot (\sqrt[4]{3^4}-1^4)}{\sqrt[4]{3}-1} = 5\left(\sqrt[4]{3^3}\cdot 1^0+\sqrt[4]{3^2}\cdot 1^1+\sqrt[4]{3^1}\cdot 1^2+\sqrt[4]{3^0}\cdot 1^3\right)$$

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much, for your explanation. I know how stupid this may seem, but could you please elaborate a little bit more? Like on why did the 10 become 5?

Comment: $10=5\cdot 2 = 5\cdot (3-1) = 5\cdot \left(\sqrt[4]{3^4}-1\right)$

Comment: OK, sorry, that was really a stupid question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not a stupid question if you understand something you did not before. I also updated my answer to make it more clear how it worked with the original hint.

Comment: This answer illustrates that you can apply the hint by setting $a = \sqrt[4]{3},$ $b = 1,$ and $n = 4,$ and dividing both sides of the equation by $a - b.$ I think this is (more or less) how the problem was intended to be solved when it was set this way.